# Why does my shell script create a file named pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe, named-pipes

I have this simple set up:

```
pwd
/home/abc/pipetest

ls
mydir  pipetest.sh
```

Now I do:

```
 ./pipetest.sh
```

And then I get

```
  ls
  file.tar.bz2  mydir  pipe  pipetest.sh
```

My question is: Why did the file named pipe get created? It contains some characters that could not be seen using vi. What's going on?

pipetest.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

directory_name=mydir
tar cf pipe $directory_name
bzip2 -c < pipe > file.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tar cf pipe $directory_name` writes the tar file to a file named `pipe`.

What you want to do is using the actual pipe:

```
tar c $directory_name | bzip2 > file.tar.bz2
```

Or simply use

```
tar cjf file.tar.bz2 $directory_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -cf pipe
```

creates a tar file named "pipe" in the current directory.