# Why doesn't the pipe command work for me?

Tags: bash, pipe, named-pipes

Actually in [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361916/pipe-command-usage-question) I was trying to use the `pipe` command. I am looking at an example in [Process Substitution - Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

I tried these lines:

```
 bzip2 -c < pipe > file.tar.bz2 & 
 tar cf pipe $directory_name 
 rm pipe
```

But they are failing with an error:

```
pipe: No such file or directory.
```

What's happening here? Is this an error in the ABS guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you're using appears to assume that the named pipe called "pipe" already exists in the current directory. The "pipe" in here:

```
bzip2 -c < pipe > file.tar.bz2 &
```

is not a command name, it is a file name that happens to be a named pipe. Do some reading on "mkfifo" and "named pipes" for more information.

Comment: Ahhh, thats why there is `rm pipe` at the end. pipe is a system call and there is no such command. I wish they had indicated somewhere that `pipe` is a pipe that should be created using mkfifo. Thanks !

Comment: If "pipe" was a command that line would have read something like this `pipe | bzip2 -c > file.tar.bz2 &`. The redirect operators (`<`, `>`, and their variants) operate on files, pipes are for commands.